# Sharepoint development using Visual Studio Express?

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, wss

Having spent the past few weeks familiarising myself with WSS 3.0 I finally want to get around to doing some Sharepoint development. I have Visual Studio Express installed on my Sharepoint server, but when I try to install the "WSS 3.0 Tools: Visual Studio Extensions" from Microsoft it tells me that I don't have Visual Studio installed.

A quick check to the pre-reqs on the download site tell me that this extension only applies to the Standard, Professional, or Team editions.

So, two questions really:

1 - Do I need the WSS Visual Studio Extension in order to do Sharepoint Development?

2 - If I do, is there a way around this (legally, of course)?

Many thanks.

Comment: Exact dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257382/can-i-use-visual-studio-express-edition-for-wss-3-0-development

Comment: @Alex - Right, I didn't spot that. But in the answer you gave to that question you said that WSPBuilder can't be used with the Express version, but Colin, in his answer to my question here, suggests that it can be used. I'll have a play around with it and see what happens.

Comment: @Simon: I've tested to double-check and unfortunately it doesn't (see the duplicate question for info on why). VS Express is designed for users learning basic dev skills, not dev with enterprise server products. Would be interesting if they made VS Pro free/cheap though.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for the feedback. My current employer is trying to keep costs as low as possible and is reluctant to pay for VS. I have my own licensed copy of VS 2008 Pro so will check out the licencing terms and conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: No, I use it only to reverse engineer list definitions etc, but you can use Stramit CamlViewer for that as well

2: No

What I believe is the easiest way to do Sharepoint development with VS is using the WSPBuilder extensions, found on CodePlex. You just recreate the "12-hive" in your VS project and add Features and such, then use WSP builder to package it all up in a deployable WSP file.

Comment: @Colin: WSPBuilder does not operate with Visual Studio Express (see dupe of this question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257382/can-i-use-visual-studio-express-edition-for-wss-3-0-development). It may be possible to just use the command line version, but difficult/unlikely. I've tested this and the WSPBuilder extensions don't show up in the VSExpress interface.

Comment: I use the Command line all the time, used the actual extensions itself once i believe). I call it from a build script / build target.

Comment: Nice, although I'd miss how WSPBuilder creates features for you within the IDE (esp. custom fields)! Would you mind updating your answer with some info or a link on how to run it in a build script? Would be interested to know.

Comment: Will post script here tomorrow and how i create VS projects screenshots