# Cannot resolve symbol 'UserProfileWebService'

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I found this article on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms550407.aspx, and I would like to use the code sample provided, but I can't seem to figure out how to resolve `UserProfileWebService`.

Does anybody know what reference do I need to add or is this some sort of SDK missing?

Also, is there any alternative to http://www.findjar.com when it comes to C#?

Any info is appreciated, thank you!

NOTE: I am a little bit of a sharepoint noob, so I might be missing some important data blocks in my head :( Also, I should point out that we are using Sharepoint 2010, VS2010, .net4.0 and Client Object Model to traverse it remotely.

Comment: do you have the sharepoint client libraries referenced?

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932617/newbie-c-question

Comment: yeah, I have both client libraries referenced, but it still won't resolve :(

Answer (score 1):

The **User Profile Service Web service** namespace is an arbitrary name for a reference to the `UserProfileService.asmx` Web service in Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007. It is in the **MOSSSOAP (in mosssoap.dll) assembly**. The `UserProfileWebService` class resides in the `websvcUserProfileService` namespace.

You need to add a reference to the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` assembly and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime` assembly.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have both of those referenced and we are making 2010 traverser if that makes a difference.

Comment: How do I get to 'websvcUserProfileService' namespace?

Comment: @Angrius that looks like a web proxy. Are you sure you're not supposed to reference a sharepoint web service?

Comment: I have no idea what I need to do honestly, all I wanted to do is use the code from the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms550407.aspx :) Now, i am confused lol

Comment: I guess there are two types of refernces: normal and service, does this mean i need to add a service reference to the UserProfileService.asmx? and can i do that if it is on a remote machine?