# SharePoint 2010 multiple users accessing same list issue

Tags: sharepoint, list, sharepoint-2010, infopath, sharepoint-designer

We have a list with 1000+ phone numbers in it. This list is sorted in a specific order by due dates and other criteria. This order is very important and needs to be maintained in the solution.

We have a group of callers (roughly 4) that will be calling the numbers in this list in the order they are sorted by. These callers are to be presented with one list item at a time, via an InfoPath form, and once they make the call they will update the list item and be presented with the next list item dictated by the sort order.

Here's the problem: This would be very easy with 1 caller but with 4 callers we don't want them calling the same people more than once. So they need grab the next list item off the top of the pile that isn't already taken by another caller.

Is there a way to build a webpart (remember without Visual Studio unfortunately) that as soon as it loads would find the first list item that is unassigned and assign it to the current user?

We could accomplish this whole thing manually of course by having an admin assign all the calls each day with a large copy/paste in Datasheet View but automatic would be soooo much better.

I will mention that I DO NOT have Visual Studio so I don't have that as an option here. But I do have SharePoint 2010, SharePoint Designer 2010, and InfoPath 2010.

I hope this makes sense and any ideas, thoughts, approaches would be greatly appreciated since I've run out! Thanks!!!!!

Comment: I really don't think you're going to find an easier solution than the one I posed in your other question (stackoverflow.com/questions/5313629/…). This is one of those things that is going to require a custom soluti

Answer (score 1):

You can develop SharePoint web parts using Visual Studio Express, but its a bit harder as you miss some of the tools that make your life easier like WSPBuilder etc.

[SO - Building webparts with Visual Studio 2010 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257382/can-i-use-visual-studio-express-edition-for-wss-3-0-development)

Another alternative would be to use javascript client side to access SharePoints Web Services via [SPService](http://spservices.codeplex.com) - then nothing more than notepad is required.

You're really using a wrench as a hammer with either of these approaches though, so I've got to say - how much do you value your time at? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can offer a very bodgy alternative; presuming all the items are added piecemeal (not in the same second). You could add a calculated column to assign each item at random on addition, using the following formula:

```
CHOOSE(MOD(SECOND([Created]),4)+1,"Operator1","Operator2","Operator3","Operator4")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a workflow that is assigned to listItem's edit; that when a caller edits its extra field like "Operating(bool)" after the calling workflow completes; the item is disabled somehow.

Only overhead of this is a caller needs to edit the item every time.

But the easy part is a listviewer webpart (oob) can be used just with a default view setting like "Operating" field is "false" only.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. On form load, instruct the form to update a status field to (let's say 'assigned') and automatically resubmit the form back. Your infopath list that pulls in the next number to call would need to exclude any that are in the assigned status. You'd also need to re-query your data connection to refresh the list each time before a call is made to grab the next available. Once the caller is finished, they can click a button that submits the form, clears the status field and closes the form.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can also pull in the active items into an infopath form using a secondary data connection. There is a way to use the insert hyperlink into the form field, and make any of your fields a URL hyperlink directly to the individual item. Although you'd have to have the URL epsaved in a field in the form the item was created in. That's easy to do, you can just con at the URL with the form name.